# Need diagonal line pattern, 10° angle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, tiles

I need a repeatable diagonal line pattern, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. I made the stripe 3px wide, then transparent spacing 6px wide, then rotated the canvas 10° (which is what I need). How can I make this into a tileable pattern?

[image]

So I followed the second answer in the duplicate question and ended up with what I needed.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a single tile to be exported, or will this remain within the Photoshop document?

Comment: I need to save it as a png and use it for a background on a website.

Comment: Here's how I'd want it to look on the site: http://i.imgur.com/5v0jOyl.png

Answer (score 0):

While it's not Photoshop, for something like this I typically use http://www.stripegenerator.com/ for some thing like this. That way you could create the stripe you want, save it out and set the image as a pattern in Photoshop and have that image for when you're looking to tile that pattern on your website.

Comment: Yeah, I checked out that website earlier. The thing is, I need it to be a specific degree. Plus that site didn't seem to have a transparency option. Thanks anyway though.